# jQuery Datapicker Dates

Tags: javascript, jquery, datapicker

Hello I have a problem with the data picker form jQuery.
The following code ignores the mindate

```
$('#datefrom').datepicker({
    minDate: '26.04.2013',
    setDate: +0,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
    onSelect: function(dateStr) {
        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
        if (date) {
              date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
        }
        $('#dateto').datepicker("setDate", date);
    }
});             
$('#dateto').datepicker({               
    minDate: '27.04.2013',
    setDate: +0,
    dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy'
});
$("#datefrom").datepicker().change(function() {
    var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
    if (date) {
          date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    }
    $('#dateto').datepicker("setDate", date);
});
$("#datefrom").datepicker('setDate', 'today');
$("#dateto").datepicker('setDate', +1);
```

To do have any idea what i could do?

Comment: What version of jQuery/jQuery UI?

Comment: jquery 1.8.2
jquery-ui 1.8.23

Comment: Seems like it's working fine... http://jsfiddle.net/ExplosionPIlls/wsvTv/

Comment: Works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/RbX3P/

Comment: try updating to jquery-ui 1.9.2 +

Comment: i have updateit on UI 1.10.1, and dont work :(

Comment: well, when I try it at your website, the mindate is at 19.02.2013.
So is it not working at all, or not working correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

minDate wants a Date-object
http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-minDate

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ minDate: new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 1) });
```

this works for me:
http://jsfiddle.net/JVueL/

Comment: show me your code in a way that I don't have to look for it half an our!

Meaning, show the important code-snippet as edit.
Because, as you can see in jsfiddle, my code works

Answer (score -2):

It must be a number, like 1, 15, 30.
    -1 - is yesterday
    0 - is today,
    1 - is tomorrow

Comment: i need to set a specific date